# getting a random entry on a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT picture.id, picture.lowresimageurl, picture.medresimageurl, picture.highresimageurl, picture.caption, picture.numberoflikes, picture.numberofdislikes 
FROM apps_instagram_picture_category category
INNER JOIN apps_instagram_shop_picture picture ON category.picture_id = picture.id
INNER JOIN apps_instagram_shop shop ON shop.id = picture.shop_id
WHERE category.first_level_category_id = ?
AND picture.deletedAt IS NULL
AND picture.isLocked = 0
AND shop.deletedAt IS NULL
AND shop.isLocked = 0
AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
AND shop.expirydate >  ?
AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY shop.id
LIMIT ?
OFFSET ?
```

I wanted to get a random picture which has a particular category X from a unique shop . The issue with this query is that it always selects the first picture it finds in the database, and hence it's not random. Any idea on how I can make it more random? I actually wanted to make the shop random as well, I can do this by giving a random offset in the query, I am however not sure on how I can get random pictures as well.

Comment: comma FROM - are you sure ? And GROUP BY? What's that for?

Comment: @Strawberry removed the typo.. the group by is because I wanted to get a picture from each unique shop

Comment: @Strawberry the ? in query is for prepared statements.

Comment: @ThiagoFrança yes it is, assume it is a number or the real value there

Comment: @ThiagoFrança Yes, it is.

Answer (score -2):

use `ORDER BY RAND()` in your query, like

```
SELECT picture.id, picture.lowresimageurl, picture.medresimageurl, picture.highresimageurl, picture.caption, picture.numberoflikes, picture.numberofdislikes 
FROM apps_instagram_shop_picture picture
INNER JOIN apps_instagram_picture_category category ON category.picture_id = picture.id
INNER JOIN apps_instagram_shop shop ON shop.id = picture.shop_id
WHERE category.first_level_category_id = ?
AND picture.deletedAt IS NULL
AND picture.isLocked = 0
AND shop.deletedAt IS NULL
AND shop.isLocked = 0
AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
AND shop.expirydate >  ?
AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY shop.id
ORDER BY shop.?, RAND()
LIMIT ?
OFFSET ?
```

Comment: this actually randomizes the order of the store but the same picture will always be selected from each store.. I wanted so that if a store has item a, b, c, d, e that matches the category then I want to make it so that it selects one of those 5 randomly each time

Comment: @adit if you need ordered shops, use `ORDER BY shop.? ASC, RAND()`.

Comment: @adit Change the `FROM` to `picture` and `INNER JOIN` to category, and you have the picture randomly. i edited my answer with the `FROM` and `INNER JOIN` clause.